# Applying CNN to Fast time Fourier Transform?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, fft, spectrogram, mel

I have data that fast time fourier transform is applied.
(amplitudes at specific Hzs)

There are solutions on internet that CNN is applied to mel spectrogram, however, I see no solution that CNN is applied to Fast Fourier Transformed signal.

Is it possible that CNN is applied to Fast Fourier Transformed signals?

Or is it not possible because CNN is considering temporal attribute?

Thanks![image]

Comment: Can you define your data a little more specifically? A spectrogram performs an FFT over a windowed segment of data with time on the X axis and the frequency response for that window of data on the Y axis. If you just do an FFT over your entire dataset then you have only the frequency response as it applies the full dataset, not over time. In this case you've thrown away most of your data. In general CNNs are particularly good at processing raw data, and the rule of thumb advice is to not apply data transformation like FFT, let the CNN learn directly from raw data.

Comment: I have no raw data(sound file), but FFT-transformed data like the image I just added in my post. The purpose of this data is to find the leakage in the water pipeline. The site is the site where the sensor system is located, and sid is the id of the sensor. lrate is the percentage that leakage happens, and the leaktype is the dependent variable that says that leakage is happened or not(in this case, the leakage did not happened and the sound signal turns out to be a normal sound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming each row of your spreadsheet is IID, e.g. it wouldn't change the problem to re-order the rows in that spreadsheet.

In this case you have a pretty typical ML problem. The fact that the FFT has already been applied and specific frequency responses (columns) have been extracted is a process called "feature engineering". Prior to the common use of neural networks, this was a standard step in all machine learning problems and remains common to a great many domains.

With data that has been feature engineered, you should look to traditional ML algorithms. Random Forests, XGBoost, and Linear Regression come to mind. A fully connected neural network is also appropriate, but I would typically expect it to under-perform other ML methods.

The hallmark of a CNN is that it operates on an ordered sequence of data. In your case the raw data, from which your dataset was derived, would be appropriate for a CNN. In a sound file you have a 1D sequence of information. You could not re-order the data in the time dimension without fundamentally changing its meaning.

A 2D CNN operates over an image where the pixel order in X and Y cannot be changed. Again the sequential order of the data matters. The same applies for 3D CNNs.

Be aware that the application of a FFT has fundamentally biased your solution by representing it only in a limited set of frequency responses. All feature engineering is fundamentally biasing the problem, presumably in a well thoughout-out way. However, it's entirely possible that other useful signals in the data exist, which aren't expressed by the FFT @ 10, 20, 30 Hz, etc. The CNN has the capacity to learn its own version of an FFT as well as other non cyclic patterns. Typically, the lack of a feature engineering step is the key differentiator between the CNN and traditional ML algorithms.